# How can I connect FastReport with MySQL 5.5 in Delphi 7?

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-7, fastreport

I use Zeos to connect MySQL 5.5 to my Delphi's application, this is why this MySQL's version does not connect correctly to Delphi 7 using its native driver.

I just can't connect to MySQL using this driver (Delphi's native one) as I can't in Delphi 7 too.

I wanna know solution(s) to connect it and of course, use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the native Borland dbExpress drivers for Delphi 7 only support really ancient versions of MySQL.  However, searching for [*mysql 5 delphi driver*](http://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+5+delphi+driver) on Google turns up several third-party drivers, such as the [dbxOpenMySQL5 driver from Just Software Solutions](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/delphi/dbexpress_and_mysql_5.html).  It's written for MySQL v5.0, but I'd say it's at least worth trying with v5.5.

There's also a [commercial MySQL dbExpress driver by Devart](http://www.devart.com/dbx/mysql/) which is explicitly [documented](http://www.devart.com/dbx/mysql/compatibility.html) as supporting MySQL 5.5 and Delphi 7.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. I got the MyDac components from Devart and it has some Fastreport components for connection with MySQL 5.5.